# What's the point of the ALL modifier in window functions?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I read the definition of the all modifier [ALL](https://www.sqlshack.com/use-window-functions-sql-server/) as

> ALL is an optional keyword. When you will include ALL it will count
>   all values including duplicate ones. DISTINCT is not supported in
>   window functions

My understanding is that it automatically would count all values anyway.

If that's the case, then why create an ALL keyword at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ALL` is pretty much never used in practice.  The point is to balance the syntax, so the default has an explicit keyword.

Similarly, some databases support `UNION DISTINCT` (which is equivalent to `UNION`) as a contrast to `UNION ALL`, to make it clear that there is an additional function on `UNION` -- the removal of duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

> *"If that's the case, then why create an ALL keyword at all?"*

There is a great Python rule called: **[EIBTI](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)**

## Explicit is better than implicit.

---

For the same reason you have constructs like:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(
  col INT NULL   -- there is no need specify NULL because column is nullable by design
);

ALTER TABLE t ADD CONSTRAINT("t_FK") FOREIGN KEY ("c_ID")
REFERENCES "t2" ("c_ID") ENABLE;   -- constraint is enabled by default
```

Every "default" behavior does not need keyword, but if we could state something explicitly why shouldn't we.